# Function Randomize - Can I get this to miss a page and just have one image on that page? Wp

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

Im working on a website and for just one page i need it to have just one image but this function keeps messing it up, Is there a way that i can tell it not to work on one page? and display one background only? here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">function Randomize() {
var images = new Array("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bgone.jpg","<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bgfour.jpg","<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bgfive.jpg","<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bgsix.jpg");
var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
document.getElementById("body-top").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";}
```

Im also using wordpress for this and this is in the header.

Thank

Comment: Can't you just reset the images variable for that 1 page.

Comment: Its in the header that is used on all pages so if i was to do that wouldn't it change on all of the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? Based off the page name pull a specific image

Use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) if you can determine a "page" if not use below to get full url to test againste

> $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

```
<?php

$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$src = '"' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images';

if($page == "Page_Name_Goes_Here")
{
  $images = $src . '/bgsix.jpg"'; // <-- image you want displayed on the 1 page
}
else 
{    
  $images  = $src . '/bgone.jpg",';
  $images .= $src . '/bgfour.jpg",';
  $images .= $src . '/bgfive.jpg",';
  $images .= $src . '/bgsix.jpg"';
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">function Randomize() {
var images = new Array(<?php echo $images; ?>);
var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
document.getElementById("body-top").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";}
```

**Output:** [Of course I do not have your bloginfo fn(), so don't know the output there]

Shows up on a specific page

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">function Randomize() {
> var images = new Array("/images/bgsix.jpg");
> var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
> document.getElementById("body-top").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";}
> ```

Does not show up on a specific page

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">function Randomize() {
> var images = new Array("/images/bgone.jpg","/images/bgfour.jpg","/images/bgfive.jpg","/images/bgsix.jpg");
> var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
> document.getElementById("body-top").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";}
> ```

Comment: Just tried this but then it only displays bgsix.jpg

Comment: echo out the $page and see if it shows the same no matter the page. This may be because of word press if that is the case then we can use the url

Comment: Just tried that and no luck, Also put in the URL but that didn't work

Comment: You need to update your question, in order to receive more feedback. Display what you have tried.

Comment: I see that you have 1 point, are you able to edit your question?

Comment: I can edit the content but not the headline /  title

Comment: Also, I think with wordpress not only must you save your change, but you might have to apply it as well.